# How to impute continuous value using categorical value

Tags: r, r-mice, imputation

I have missing values in a continuous vector

```
y <- c(8, 7, NA, 4, 6)
```

I have zip code

```
x <- factor(c("94562", "98705", "94122", "94539", "94122"))
```

I would like to use zip code to impute y. I have tried

```
library(mice)
mice.impute.norm(y = y, ry = is.na(y), x = x)
```

But I get error indicating it can't do the crossproduct (specific message can't be posted because my rstudio session is hanging).

Any ideas on how to do this with mice or another package?

---

## edit: `dput` of part of data

```
structure(list(P = c(430978, 258197, 441424, 4697124, 549553, 
543517, 164859, 878202, 552206, 1277737, 622493, 0, 386436, 296388, 
396152, 2085540, 0, 872755, 705626, 1165616, 660079, 0, 854224, 
2467241, NA, 327414, 172844, 1225882, 392000, 1212863, 482001, 
323318, 854862, 282000, 197983, 0, 257816, 3184589, NA, NA, 351540, 
519250, 0, 715735, 440319, 269234, 473734, 115562, 196519, 578946, 
0, 310298, 1144127, 1245472, 573946, 637205, NA, 202050, NA, 
968296, 2510965, 651258, 358531, 858467, 238151, 1334602, 1724823, 
439336, 113247, 1739823, 918437, 2089680, 390012, 878560, 734073, 
835640, 421741, 823924, 1169276, 388136, 313059, 834817, 750854, 
0, 200761, 871028, 521642, 611000, 1001221, 607588, 596879, 1818999, 
1997605, 634628, 720182, 276853, 1082990, 462157, 162590, 498092, 
395789, 630174, 697803, 780158, 381650, 259782, 540757, 731815, 
1002691, 0, 153433, 416352, 1111262, 1076702, 1286831, 555605, 
0, 139202, 640845, 327670, 269729, 155641, 435379, 833306, 1615806, 
201458, 714396, 282184, 721273, 1442403, 511897, 447289, NA, 
941232, 428255, 3293079, 180466, 394853, NA, 0, 636945, 775164, 
930795, 1758912, 751042, 2006928, 168166, 440602, 967278, 498395, 
2267808, 1677245, 1767264, 411715, 776274, NA, 0, 649445, 467611, 
381720, 1154060, 1338408, 1245837, 771673, NA, 1671251, 1179100, 
1774379, 323477, 2316334, 649605, 212284, 408611, 404153, 649797, 
0, 122709, 776319, 1681236, 265285, 145190, 829636, 170889, 535429, 
453658, 845000, 728687, 1425078, 750081, 0, 943963, 692388, 310913, 
482516, 265311, 295152, 852276, 841878, 367349, 571220, 940994, 
668783, 231262, 2285178, 499754, 2481758, 2552567, 1209911, 1309048, 
0, NA, 970914, 143681, 117653, 2559991, 1530288, 998852, 972048, 
501345, NA, 455011, 1090249, 0, 1754717, 928676, 2228952, 1210306, 
274114, 2996674, 1373548, 348015, 481149, 247406, 1465976, 1843617, 
0, 187732, NA, 730044, 690627, 273611, 2555635, 741534, 678164, 
0, 1174674, 1141709, 1017413, 128923, 880700, 0, 514569, 0, 3981143, 
322187, 780000, 1308740, 275292, 228581, 1673234, 625399, 404182, 
619844, 0, 235631, 0, 981673, 389150, 353951, 326345, 214020, 
1968243, 252044, 209535, 992147, 764947, 543495, 2647744, 530914, 
613501, NA, 278428, 670708, 985255, 1287827, 2597156, 765840, 
0, 1444604, 265677, 993149, 464696, 356783, 590535, 318429, 2086138, 
391269, 567151, 386370, 107666, 406000, 364883, 913950, 336508, 
565462, 0, 737092, 275279, 404449, 486438, 180063, 283177, 1876736, 
524425, 1004098, 347263, 599265, 252279, 1018000, 0, 184479, 
659572, 1876473, 144852, 0, 0, 0, 253781, 284629, 200933, 1333446, 
854077, 625488, 1250172, 224754, 882517, 231475, 166978, 735607, 
230509, 800756, 784914, 420270, 185336, 246928, 614803, 1371731, 
0, 207045, 276819, 512905, 199201, 217407, 282554, NA, 482712, 
950772, 1165216, 0, 447145, 407478, 1384973, 481090, 671244, 
351402, 637502, 553362, 789929, 745108, 271497, 787057, 2623938, 
927413, 774508, 500969, 964854, 526529, 668668, 1126112, 731235, 
1544305, NA, 0, 309125, 457086, 127128, 446126, 139772, 358053, 
363871, 522786, 916538, 452719, 383917, 637407, 336294, 1514003, 
766945, 439585, 301085, 301074, 266695, 346461, 131531, 189778, 
420600, 630623, 179731, 368203, 243744, 518385, 578028, 359323, 
1201273, 1966185, 611000, 305056, 0, 0, 763189, 457651, 2095788, 
2502161, 1904274, 305234, 376261, 1324896, 377826, 1218535, 175428, 
398371, 625510, 555790, NA, 739395, 528774, 1224491, 666071, 
304766, 1136009, 469271, NA, 328784, 399521, NA, 960898, 939321, 
628866, 267014, 352126, 392874, 1403416, 779563, 1454036, 365208, 
1019950, 261490, 181000, NA, 0, NA, 0, 754076, 1154453, 1046000, 
3056705, 147467, 172242, 481561, 1501393, 1023301, 625225, 389466, 
71127, 1225320, 0, 734682, 237290, 957442, 309519, 356858, 233500, 
177190, 486064, NA, 619008, 1348038, 751197, 1557408, 712051, 
1311732, 627650, 292000, 0, 768646, 431135, 637152, 398952, 438161, 
186194, 361569, 232833, 889680, NA, 1132797, 669670, 451444, 
393618, 1257769, 848298, 1076782, 245171, 0, 280950, 0, 0, 1641403, 
439986, 330774, 359512, 1028509, 679340, 371646, 474494, 797887, 
287127, 294498, 714913, 166292, 383565, 643625, 0, 2150467, 244742, 
1764309, 924075, 969097, 1839615, 796188, 1364330, 405164, 216870, 
0, 5785310, 530395, 1043911, 614367, 517762, 537112, 1161056, 
507340, 2219940, 1783959, 391147, 512239, 187435, 0, 1308179, 
0, 970877, 798663, NA, 1524668, 1011186, 555983, 998058, 269345, 
393185, 2187930, 520688, 0, 1399948, 0, 1135497, 730279, 1468040, 
434088, 1450764, NA, 541791, 700064, 919461, 0, 1023378, 1240075, 
547794, 968996, 240392, 358874, 195951, 949183, 1070050, 163521, 
0, 483058, 1784686, 0, 1247666, 1195258, NA, 1044343, 1443992, 
812583, 936031, 190546, 388127, 0, 495595, 377471, 575207, 2608400, 
233725, 0, 465783, 378966, 0, 363322, 1018468, 816970, 0, 1485934, 
700082, 1923973, 5603372, 1890049, 1926850, 0, 443506, 172164, 
658800, 336870, 550835, 1098827, 1398211, 343704, 851671, 1283774, 
337959, 1346075, 1452629, 581806, 885973, 610659, 693601, 3937677, 
92446, 317879, 753399, 309471, 501656, 482898, 1508468, 946956, 
0, 894148, 376428, NA, 666900, 2228116, 1734511, 414936, 633964, 
429246, 0, 282809, NA, 556125, 404724, 396565, 308760, 415532, 
855008, 130680, 450144, 668459, 162911, 578297, 199129, 2180912, 
3818836, 128208, NA, 204887, 812150, 247087, 626391, 1030287, 
202166, 316501, 392917, 622271, 0, 523260, 709000, 185786, 1518284, 
852749, 308630, 0, 1280117, 499133, 560035, 913103, 357553, 861170, 
2300529, 0, 969203, 780080, 386323, NA, 1177880, 534566, 1736941, 
635773, 2568170, 291748, 464465, 665993, 299345, 1728483, 805991, 
261636, 606749, NA, 785862, 2638239, 1744052, 566641, 511034, 
388557, 278391, 892563, 324254, NA, 354527, 1229760, 532942, 
987340, 3183471, 260660, 1531932, 549854, 2020837, 0, 395248, 
127387, 602795, 332431, 506106, 759821, 213757, 970139, 554647, 
708758, 1131534, 546207, 0, 415942, 1176368, 605931, 0, 691959, 
1404907, 565904, 607480, 312361, 163000, 212417, 277627, 1737963, 
1150777, 124624, 209945, 1123399, 581433, 675144, 0, 703212, 
1930374, 404589, 966181, 930596, 614151, 133066, 115956, 176013, 
0, 338516, 1575332, 725400, 390636, 624768, 1261313, 629072, 
204297, 323404, 1151330, 589984, 2305308, NA, 421961, 360286, 
935414, NA, NA, 354431, 766989, 97042, 215050, 935844, 947514, 
641636, 430436, 679528, 762154, 1256202, 173160, 678178, 732307, 
922627, 144878, 1156409, 751874, 0, 327670, 358266, 256644, 868852, 
393758, NA, 902305, 1397937, 257786, 411285, 2168876, 0, 399356, 
663956, 410679, 1349445, 1697725, 679709, 427320, 180366, 4617713, 
152158, 563863, 409620, 673038, 438582, 773626, 372557, 1426526, 
855065, 0, 0, 381822, 394079, 759169, 383184, 642847, 765006, 
0, 634560, 383000, NA, 326743, 1002299, 837598, 355404, 297186, 
1399055, 393458, 80914, 1085741, 2422294, 409800, 621836, 377000, 
744659, 1107878, 649213, 1054000, NA, 741798, 539339, 900273, 
452743, 0, 1210658, 604932, 425000, 752925, 1090672, 394228, 
392651, NA, 323997, 0, 0, 919320, 0, 261913, 264578, 385369, 
307634, 250357, 469804, NA, 508604, 115314, 627150, 228478, 1565967, 
159983, 326029, 303076, 801901, 663535, 982720, 464038, 670967, 
0, 0, 1420048, 612840, 883903, 0, 339793, 361892, 299232, 368794, 
0, 1426134, 3097892, 1e+05, 359364, 0, 616904, 927555, 591748, 
753366, 534360, 698168, 949580, 1190253, 1530686, 822148, 383847, 
922607, 0, 420181, 302075, 155873, 300821, 288721, 304443, 131176, 
907342, 208983, 0, 697454, 1271716, 1756495, 469613, 864668, 
1046899, 1253490, 952853, 911874, 232009, NA, 4596832, 297199, 
969819, 162546, 679205, 714091, 0, 845583, 350619, 475221, 507543, 
130055, 0, 376177, 280697, 485000, 2593670, 1063130, 472895, 
1706345, NA, 292021, 1214084, 623396, NA, 570721, NA), Z = structure(c(440L, 
98L, 108L, 372L, 458L, 152L, 234L, 125L, 350L, 75L, 677L, 434L, 
463L, 142L, 648L, 504L, 503L, 502L, 81L, 72L, 59L, 567L, 572L, 
126L, 508L, 653L, 43L, 380L, 549L, 688L, 191L, 196L, 510L, 184L, 
190L, 2L, 224L, 523L, 225L, 575L, 236L, 242L, 556L, 231L, 257L, 
255L, 246L, 248L, 254L, 260L, 283L, 392L, 396L, 468L, 455L, 181L, 
348L, 285L, 11L, 18L, 596L, 67L, 27L, 31L, 346L, 579L, 68L, 167L, 
309L, 631L, 385L, 661L, 310L, 678L, 422L, 424L, 686L, 436L, 436L, 
437L, 302L, 388L, 153L, 480L, 327L, 168L, 495L, 36L, 572L, 420L, 
451L, 603L, 628L, 633L, 106L, 118L, 97L, 100L, 159L, 187L, 496L, 
284L, 306L, 166L, 202L, 210L, 447L, 469L, 460L, 368L, 219L, 224L, 
650L, 690L, 585L, 239L, 386L, 252L, 558L, 275L, 248L, 272L, 287L, 
379L, 379L, 290L, 304L, 301L, 574L, 590L, 324L, 9L, 331L, 22L, 
341L, 638L, 343L, 353L, 614L, 365L, 78L, 628L, 88L, 623L, 232L, 
637L, 148L, 666L, 411L, 657L, 671L, 422L, 373L, 170L, 691L, 438L, 
471L, 115L, 400L, 299L, 351L, 473L, 173L, 155L, 587L, 79L, 532L, 
396L, 478L, 22L, 642L, 251L, 99L, 182L, 552L, 484L, 129L, 641L, 
199L, 193L, 153L, 52L, 184L, 171L, 445L, 518L, 428L, 428L, 219L, 
639L, 536L, 546L, 228L, 256L, 264L, 374L, 380L, 426L, 294L, 354L, 
452L, 335L, 568L, 568L, 1L, 4L, 321L, 11L, 339L, 386L, 22L, 594L, 
37L, 44L, 619L, 63L, 621L, 617L, 80L, 628L, 377L, 631L, 94L, 
636L, 641L, 664L, 655L, 670L, 421L, 379L, 686L, 447L, 132L, 115L, 
234L, 299L, 323L, 487L, 456L, 563L, 156L, 373L, 573L, 451L, 615L, 
628L, 633L, 668L, 62L, 127L, 397L, 67L, 67L, 212L, 419L, 220L, 
218L, 219L, 224L, 597L, 530L, 238L, 3L, 229L, 249L, 200L, 364L, 
144L, 382L, 173L, 291L, 672L, 324L, 308L, 348L, 116L, 358L, 32L, 
580L, 165L, 28L, 42L, 606L, 507L, 605L, 613L, 621L, 362L, 623L, 
74L, 89L, 634L, 102L, 446L, 419L, 422L, 684L, 119L, 437L, 695L, 
467L, 476L, 461L, 135L, 314L, 413L, 581L, 673L, 79L, 110L, 357L, 
477L, 451L, 624L, 633L, 394L, 646L, 84L, 589L, 488L, 185L, 123L, 
195L, 184L, 519L, 450L, 219L, 221L, 226L, 233L, 640L, 30L, 235L, 
534L, 41L, 174L, 350L, 277L, 543L, 298L, 296L, 333L, 305L, 483L, 
308L, 512L, 70L, 6L, 330L, 337L, 594L, 44L, 349L, 346L, 613L, 
559L, 63L, 69L, 365L, 54L, 77L, 631L, 89L, 414L, 694L, 293L, 
160L, 464L, 234L, 436L, 527L, 522L, 463L, 265L, 172L, 60L, 557L, 
557L, 561L, 423L, 423L, 628L, 616L, 494L, 297L, 203L, 338L, 122L, 
207L, 468L, 222L, 219L, 444L, 481L, 650L, 43L, 449L, 544L, 231L, 
259L, 250L, 261L, 266L, 281L, 286L, 420L, 383L, 326L, 300L, 514L, 
10L, 329L, 329L, 14L, 19L, 117L, 593L, 244L, 621L, 87L, 381L, 
88L, 523L, 643L, 401L, 654L, 462L, 412L, 454L, 669L, 431L, 672L, 
687L, 682L, 91L, 117L, 428L, 684L, 46L, 436L, 86L, 48L, 139L, 
143L, 506L, 474L, 149L, 164L, 398L, 410L, 178L, 607L, 649L, 545L, 
59L, 630L, 361L, 395L, 562L, 591L, 213L, 608L, 622L, 55L, 158L, 
679L, 497L, 152L, 204L, 126L, 462L, 219L, 651L, 45L, 536L, 230L, 
265L, 265L, 572L, 244L, 248L, 276L, 261L, 334L, 291L, 453L, 389L, 
393L, 396L, 383L, 304L, 403L, 311L, 336L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 303L, 
312L, 313L, 346L, 625L, 355L, 57L, 621L, 69L, 242L, 76L, 88L, 
88L, 90L, 384L, 381L, 401L, 402L, 670L, 113L, 419L, 141L, 429L, 
511L, 689L, 433L, 693L, 680L, 459L, 515L, 149L, 351L, 175L, 498L, 
646L, 521L, 40L, 609L, 676L, 63L, 186L, 322L, 572L, 470L, 221L, 
598L, 599L, 531L, 537L, 550L, 265L, 265L, 273L, 364L, 273L, 404L, 
305L, 292L, 308L, 586L, 130L, 592L, 600L, 12L, 43L, 353L, 618L, 
620L, 623L, 359L, 74L, 85L, 634L, 92L, 614L, 643L, 643L, 652L, 
105L, 662L, 659L, 661L, 415L, 685L, 686L, 660L, 469L, 466L, 49L, 
115L, 146L, 315L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 399L, 535L, 551L, 569L, 485L, 
517L, 501L, 387L, 452L, 630L, 33L, 117L, 38L, 112L, 151L, 220L, 
233L, 651L, 533L, 272L, 240L, 278L, 361L, 363L, 318L, 576L, 25L, 
329L, 21L, 134L, 124L, 611L, 575L, 597L, 612L, 43L, 69L, 66L, 
442L, 629L, 631L, 631L, 634L, 51L, 113L, 269L, 683L, 448L, 436L, 
93L, 390L, 451L, 555L, 128L, 154L, 153L, 480L, 237L, 168L, 411L, 
570L, 503L, 502L, 557L, 416L, 583L, 613L, 633L, 180L, 96L, 96L, 
56L, 486L, 489L, 493L, 194L, 83L, 284L, 301L, 164L, 184L, 202L, 
219L, 219L, 542L, 224L, 524L, 524L, 520L, 147L, 435L, 547L, 262L, 
374L, 379L, 289L, 454L, 295L, 396L, 8L, 360L, 586L, 24L, 602L, 
103L, 344L, 613L, 619L, 69L, 502L, 61L, 375L, 631L, 633L, 644L, 
502L, 663L, 665L, 113L, 559L, 681L, 113L, 26L, 411L, 459L, 443L, 
578L, 177L, 588L, 503L, 82L, 72L, 216L, 571L, 597L, 632L, 50L, 
183L, 71L, 692L, 491L, 211L, 499L, 301L, 541L, 539L, 104L, 521L, 
223L, 523L, 234L, 586L, 353L, 235L, 282L, 376L, 316L, 389L, 389L, 
179L, 455L, 301L, 425L, 432L, 577L, 319L, 554L, 321L, 17L, 591L, 
105L, 601L, 216L, 29L, 40L, 656L, 47L, 354L, 628L, 107L, 408L, 
654L, 411L, 661L, 578L, 189L, 681L, 681L, 439L, 472L, 451L, 475L, 
150L, 205L, 188L, 279L, 197L, 163L, 564L, 133L, 503L, 59L, 522L, 
39L, 361L, 161L, 479L, 628L, 633L, 101L, 120L, 426L, 426L, 491L, 
492L, 138L, 136L, 247L, 283L, 138L, 500L, 198L, 111L, 209L, 532L, 
217L, 505L, 577L, 601L, 233L, 529L, 537L, 325L, 243L, 250L, 271L, 
242L, 266L, 270L, 465L, 513L, 202L, 140L, 455L, 1L, 565L, 578L, 
584L, 15L, 594L, 20L, 342L, 43L, 604L, 44L, 356L, 47L, 345L, 
346L, 595L, 58L, 618L, 698L, 366L, 369L, 241L, 109L, 406L, 405L, 
419L, 672L, 675L, 696L, 687L, 427L, 391L, 13L, 466L, 248L, 53L, 
603L, 340L, 171L, 409L, 417L, 516L, 528L, 647L, 526L, 373L, 623L, 
635L, 34L, 95L, 73L, 426L, 482L, 560L, 490L, 192L, 283L, 335L, 
206L, 227L, 209L, 407L, 208L, 220L, 525L, 548L, 566L, 245L, 250L, 
265L, 269L, 268L, 278L, 674L, 274L, 263L, 370L, 270L, 371L, 288L, 
393L, 292L, 320L, 441L, 332L, 336L, 378L, 307L, 365L, 568L, 318L, 
586L, 317L, 35L, 46L, 344L, 347L, 366L, 16L, 619L, 64L, 65L, 
367L, 627L, 630L, 645L, 645L, 430L, 672L, 114L, 425L, 253L, 428L, 
121L, 691L, 697L, 145L, 457L, 131L, 267L, 280L, 328L, 352L, 169L, 
157L, 7L, 610L, 523L, 619L, 82L, 526L, 72L, 582L, 380L, 583L, 
418L, 615L, 600L, 509L, 667L, 647L, 658L, 137L, 23L, 486L, 201L, 
171L, 214L, 215L, 5L, 162L, 176L, 626L, 519L, 619L, 236L, 540L, 
448L, 243L, 538L, 553L, 258L, 258L, 258L), .Label = c("10010", 
"10018", "10019", "10022", "10023", "10030", "10032", "10065", 
"10309", "10310", "10510", "10518", "10533", "10538", "10576", 
"10580", "10589", "10597", "10708", "10960", "11020", "11201", 
"11211", "11226", "11229", "11552", "11565", "11566", "11705", 
"11733", "11937", "11962", "11963", "11976", "12159", "1451", 
"14620", "15010", "1504", "15102", "15211", "15215", "15228", 
"15234", "15236", "15241", "15317", "1536", "15367", "17036", 
"17050", "1742", "18015", "18077", "1810", "1824", "18249", "18708", 
"1890", "18938", "19010", "19026", "19035", "19036", "19040", 
"19060", "19073", "19085", "19087", "19118", "19128", "1921", 
"19317", "19335", "19382", "19403", "19426", "19438", "1945", 
"19460", "1950", "1960", "19610", "19713", "19805", "1983", "20003", 
"20007", "20008", "20016", "20105", "20118", "20124", "20131", 
"20135", "20165", "20170", "20175", "20176", "20190", "20191", 
"20198", "2026", "2067", "20814", "20833", "20895", "21037", 
"21146", "2132", "2135", "2140", "22101", "22201", "22207", "22304", 
"22314", "22724", "23113", "23192", "23225", "23233", "23451", 
"2465", "2478", "2481", "2492", "26037", "26038", "2633", "26501", 
"27127", "2747", "2748", "27502", "27514", "27516", "27517", 
"27518", "27519", "27587", "2760", "27613", "27614", "27701", 
"28056", "2817", "28173", "28203", "28205", "28207", "28210", 
"28211", "28226", "2842", "2865", "2888", "2891", "29205", "29401", 
"29466", "30004", "30024", "30062", "30075", "30080", "30265", 
"30305", "30309", "30312", "30319", "3032", "30324", "30327", 
"30338", "30341", "30345", "30519", "32082", "32708", "32765", 
"32766", "32779", "32792", "32803", "32806", "32817", "32818", 
"32859", "32940", "33016", "33138", "33143", "33176", "33301", 
"33405", "33408", "33414", "33431", "33458", "33463", "33558", 
"33604", "33606", "33609", "33613", "33618", "33625", "33626", 
"33701", "33764", "33767", "34102", "34219", "34983", "34990", 
"35126", "35205", "35213", "35222", "35226", "35242", "35243", 
"35244", "35901", "35951", "3608", "36207", "36265", "36305", 
"37027", "37064", "37138", "37205", "37212", "37215", "37220", 
"42103", "43004", "43022", "43023", "43054", "43055", "43085", 
"43201", "43209", "43212", "43214", "43220", "43221", "44120", 
"44121", "44124", "44130", "44236", "45011", "45040", "45215", 
"45243", "45419", "45429", "45434", "45449", "45690", "46032", 
"46074", "46168", "46202", "46208", "46226", "46260", "47906", 
"48009", "48025", "48073", "48085", "48092", "48098", "48124", 
"48128", "48152", "48216", "48302", "48304", "48310", "48336", 
"48371", "48382", "48439", "49201", "49203", "50131", "50266", 
"52245", "53066", "53125", "53213", "53226", "55044", "55105", 
"55122", "55306", "55318", "55331", "55345", "55347", "55391", 
"55407", "55408", "55410", "55416", "55438", "55439", "55441", 
"55446", "60005", "60010", "60015", "60045", "60056", "60091", 
"60093", "60119", "60126", "60137", "60148", "60173", "60187", 
"60201", "60408", "60515", "60516", "60521", "60527", "60558", 
"60564", "60565", "60585", "60610", "60614", "60622", "60625", 
"61455", "62002", "63011", "63021", "63026", "63108", "63117", 
"63119", "63122", "63123", "63124", "63128", "63131", "63367", 
"6360", "64108", "64112", "64113", "6437", "66047", "66061", 
"6612", "66206", "66207", "66223", "66227", "67219", "6807", 
"6820", "6831", "6840", "6850", "68502", "6851", "68516", "6870", 
"6880", "6897", "70005", "7005", "7006", "70116", "70130", "7030", 
"7031", "7041", "7042", "7045", "7047", "7067", "7068", "7079", 
"7086", "7090", "7104", "72118", "72205", "74008", "74037", "74044", 
"7450", "7458", "75007", "75024", "75028", "75149", "75205", 
"75223", "75225", "75244", "75762", "76107", "76132", "76244", 
"76262", "7701", "77018", "7702", "77024", "77027", "7704", "77056", 
"77057", "7733", "77381", "77401", "77459", "77493", "77578", 
"78006", "78023", "78028", "78130", "78209", "78218", "78248", 
"78249", "78260", "7853", "78613", "78624", "78633", "78717", 
"78730", "78731", "78735", "78746", "78759", "7901", "7920", 
"7922", "7928", "7940", "79407", "80012", "80016", "80020", "80108", 
"80111", "80113", "80121", "80134", "80205", "80206", "80207", 
"80209", "80210", "80211", "80218", "80231", "80238", "80439", 
"80504", "80516", "80525", "8055", "8057", "80906", "80908", 
"80919", "8096", "81612", "83816", "84010", "84045", "84061", 
"84062", "84098", "84103", "84105", "84108", "84121", "85016", 
"85018", "85021", "85045", "85253", "85255", "85258", "85259", 
"85260", "85262", "85331", "8558", "86001", "8730", "8742", "87505", 
"87506", "8801", "8812", "8852", "8873", "90032", "90036", "90048", 
"90049", "90068", "90212", "90265", "90266", "90402", "90404", 
"90503", "90630", "90706", "90740", "90803", "91001", "91011", 
"91030", "91107", "91109", "91207", "91208", "91302", "91303", 
"91316", "91356", "91360", "91362", "91377", "91403", "91411", 
"91506", "91709", "91740", "91773", "91803", "91902", "92007", 
"92056", "92067", "92068", "92117", "92131", "92253", "92603", 
"92617", "92625", "92627", "92629", "92630", "92656", "92658", 
"92660", "92661", "92663", "92672", "92673", "92675", "92677", 
"92679", "92688", "92691", "92692", "92694", "92821", "92833", 
"92886", "93003", "93004", "93035", "93101", "93103", "93105", 
"93108", "93117", "93190", "93532", "93536", "94002", "94019", 
"94022", "94025", "94026", "94027", "94028", "94030", "94043", 
"94061", "94062", "94070", "94080", "94110", "94114", "94118", 
"94122", "94123", "94129", "94301", "94303", "94304", "94306", 
"94501", "94506", "94507", "94518", "94526", "94536", "94549", 
"94553", "94571", "94595", "94602", "94611", "94805", "94901", 
"94925", "94939", "94941", "94947", "94965", "95003", "95030", 
"95032", "95065", "95070", "95125", "95128", "95476", "95613", 
"95616", "95630", "95648", "95661", "95677", "95746", "95747", 
"95816", "95926", "97007", "97034", "97086", "97103", "97201", 
"97205", "97209", "97210", "97211", "97212", "97219", "97221", 
"97223", "97229", "97239", "97376", "97702", "98004", "98033", 
"98036", "98038", "98046", "98053", "98072", "98075", "98101", 
"98103", "98105", "98110", "98112", "98115", "98117", "98125", 
"98126", "98144", "98146", "98178", "98199", "98223", "98236", 
"98260", "98312", "98392", "98506", "98686"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("P", 
"Z"), row.names = c(NA, -1000L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What method of imputation are you looking for? Mean, mode...?

Comment: In this example you have no repeated zip codes so the zip code adds no useful information. Is that true for your real data too?

Comment: I would settle for anything. I wanted to test out several different methods.

Comment: Hi Gregor, no that was an error on my part. I have updated. Ty

Comment: If you'll settle for anything, try the mean imputation.

Comment: @RaphaelK I'll settle for any type of imputation that relates x to y.

Comment: Can you post some of your data, it's hard to give you a good answer otherwise.  Try `dput(your_data)`.  I say this because, as @Gregor mentioned, it's hard to understand how x and y are related.

Comment: Your example data only has two repeated `Z`s and and neither of them have associated missing values in `P`. Please provide a useful example.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this, assuming you have a dataframe with `zipcode` and `y`:

You could create such a dataframe with your starting data with:

```
df <- data.frame("zipcode" = x, y)
```

Using data tables

```
library(data.table)

# Create an imputation function for values that are NA
impute.mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

# Cast df as a data table
df <- as.data.table(df)

# Use the function to impute y by zipcode
df[, y := impute.mean(y), by = zipcode]
```

Using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

# Create an imputation function for values that are NA
impute.mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

# Use dplyr to group by and run function
df <- df %>%
  group_by(zipcode) %>%
  mutate(
    y = impute.mean(y)
  )
```

I would suggest searching around a bit next time; this question has probably been answered before, such as here:

[How to replace NA with mean by subset in R (impute with plyr?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322773/how-to-replace-na-with-mean-by-subset-in-r-impute-with-plyr)

Comment: Thanks. That helps. I did search around quite a bit, but apparently didn't have the search terms correct. To anyone: Is there any way to make use of the many methods in the `mice` or `missForest` package using a factor such as zip code for x?

Comment: The example in the OP used the `mice` package, which imputes multiple values from a normal distribution, conditional on other variables. Mean imputation is *hugely* different from that, and isn't at all suited for many statistical tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `norm` method in `mice` is that it doesn't recognize factor variables as other functions in R do (e.g., `lm`). Therefore, if your goal is to condition on a categorical variable, you have to do some kind of coding for the factor variable first.

Here is an example using a dummy coding scheme for the categorical variable.

```
# create data set with dummy coding for Z
dat.dummy <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(~Z, data=dat))
dat.dummy$P <- dat$P

# empty imputation (provides a template for the "predictorMatrix" and
# "method" arguments)
library(mice)
imp0 <- mice(dat.dummy, m=5, maxit=0)

# get defaults
predMatrix <- imp0$predictorMatrix
impMethod <- imp0$method

# choose "norm" for P (instead of the default "pmm")
impMethod["P"] <- "norm"

# impute 5 times, using 5 iterations each
imp1 <- mice(dat.dummy, m=5, maxit=5)
```

The dummy coding is done automatically when using `model matrix()`, this creating a series of indicator variables that denote the different levels in `Z`.

Using the dummy coded data, `mice` will do what you were going for.