# Replace NA with mean of variable grouped by time and treatment

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a data frame, similar to the one below (see dput), recording responses of a variable to a treatment over time:

```
df <- structure(list( time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90),
                      trt = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                      .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
               A1 = c(6.301, 5.426, 5.6021, NA, NA, NA, 6.1663, 6.426, 6.8239, 2.301, 4.7047, 2.301, 5.8062, 4.97, 4.97, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301),
               B1 = c(5.727, 5.727, 5.4472, NA, NA, NA, 6.6021, 7.028, 7.1249, 3.028, 3.1663, 3.6021, 5.727, 5.2711, 5.2389, 3.3554, 3.9031, 4.2389, 3.727, 3.6021, 3.6021, 3.8239, 3.727, 3.426)),
               row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks lie this:

```
    time trt      A1    B1
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 2      6.30  5.73
 2     0 2      5.43  5.73
 3     0 2      5.60  5.45
 4     0 1     NA    NA   
 5     0 1     NA    NA   
 6     0 1     NA    NA   
 7    14 2      6.17  6.60
 8    14 2      6.43  7.03
 9    14 2      6.82  7.12
10    14 1      2.30  3.03
```

In our experiments, we don’t always record values for all treatments at time == 0.  I want to replace any missing values (NA) when (and only when) time == 0 with the mean of the trt ‘2’ group at time == 0.  So NA in A1 all become 5.78, and those in B1 become 5.63.

Using answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322773/how-to-replace-na-with-mean-by-group-subset), as well as some others, I have been able to come up with the following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(if_else(is.na(.),if_else(time == 0, 0, .), .)))
```

This replaces NA at time == 0 with 0 (this is useful for some of my variables where there is no data in any of the treatments at time == 0, but not what i'm after here).  I also tried this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(if_else(is.na(.),if_else(time == 0, mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .), .)))
```

This is closer to what I want, but is averaging the values from the whole column/variable.  Can I make it average only those values from treatment ‘2’ when time == 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would just use indexing in base R for this:

```r
within(df, {A1[is.na(A1) & time == 0] <- mean(A1[trt == "2" & time == 0])
            B1[is.na(B1) & time == 0] <- mean(B1[trt == "2" & time == 0])})
#> # A tibble: 24 x 4
#>     time trt      A1    B1
#>    <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0 2      6.30  5.73
#>  2     0 2      5.43  5.73
#>  3     0 2      5.60  5.45
#>  4     0 1      5.78  5.63
#>  5     0 1      5.78  5.63
#>  6     0 1      5.78  5.63
#>  7    14 2      6.17  6.60
#>  8    14 2      6.43  7.03
#>  9    14 2      6.82  7.12
#> 10    14 1      2.30  3.03
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as i wanted.  As i have more than 2 variables to apply this to, is it possible to do this without explicitly stating each variable?  e.g. could i try this in a loop, and loop through A1, B1, C1 etc?

Comment: something like this:  `for (i in c("A1", "B1")){
within(df, {i[is.na(i) & time == 0] <- mean(i[trt == "2" & time == 0])})}` but its giving error:  `In mean.default(i[trt == "2" & time == 0]) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Answer (score 1):

If we add `group_by(time)`, we can recode the missing columns to the time-specific mean values for the observations where `time == 0` as follows.

```
df <- structure(list( time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90),
                      trt = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                      .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
                      A1 = c(6.301, 5.426, 5.6021, NA, NA, NA, 6.1663, 6.426, 6.8239, 2.301, 4.7047, 2.301, 5.8062, 4.97, 4.97, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301, 2.301),
                      B1 = c(5.727, 5.727, 5.4472, NA, NA, NA, 6.6021, 7.028, 7.1249, 3.028, 3.1663, 3.6021, 5.727, 5.2711, 5.2389, 3.3554, 3.9031, 4.2389, 3.727, 3.6021, 3.6021, 3.8239, 3.727, 3.426)),
                row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(time)  %>%
     mutate(A1 = if_else(is.na(A1) & time == 0,mean(A1,na.rm=TRUE),A1),
            B1 = if_else(is.na(B1) & time == 0,mean(B1,na.rm=TRUE),B1))
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 4
# Groups:   time [4]
    time trt      A1    B1
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 2      6.30  5.73
 2     0 2      5.43  5.73
 3     0 2      5.60  5.45
 4     0 1      5.78  5.63
 5     0 1      5.78  5.63
 6     0 1      5.78  5.63
 7    14 2      6.17  6.60
 8    14 2      6.43  7.03
 9    14 2      6.82  7.12
10    14 1      2.30  3.03
# ... with 14 more rows
>
```

### UPDATE: general solution across multiple columns

Per the comments in my answer, here is a solution that uses the development version of `dplyr` to access the new `across()` function.

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr") # needed for across()
# get all columns except time and trt
theColumns <- colnames(df)[!(colnames(df) %in% c("time","trt"))]
df %>% group_by(time)  %>%
     mutate(across(theColumns,~if_else(is.na(.) & time == 0,mean(.,na.rm=TRUE),.)))
```

...and the output:

```
# Groups:   time [4]
    time trt      A1    B1
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 2      6.30  5.73
 2     0 2      5.43  5.73
 3     0 2      5.60  5.45
 4     0 1      5.78  5.63
 5     0 1      5.78  5.63
 6     0 1      5.78  5.63
 7    14 2      6.17  6.60
 8    14 2      6.43  7.03
 9    14 2      6.82  7.12
10    14 1      2.30  3.03
# … with 14 more rows
>
```

Comment: thanks for this - i would prefer a tidyverse / dplyr solution such as yours, but this one also replaces NA in groups other than time == 0, which i do not want...

Comment: @Mark - Given the test data, it was unclear that you wanted to leave other time values as NA. This is easily fixed (see minor adjustment in my answer).

Comment: thanks for the update. Same question to you as to Alen (apologies for lack of clarity in the question), can this be applied to a group of variables without explicitly naming them as you have, that is - do the same thing to A1, B1, C1 etc?

Comment: @Mark - yes, will post an update later this evening US hours.

Comment: @Mark -- see updated answer, using `dplyr` 1.0.0 and its new `across()` function.

Comment: thanks for the update - installing the developer version seems to have been beyond me (broke a few things trying!) but i will definitely check out the solution using across() once dplyr 1.0.0 is ready

Answer (score 0):

As i was unable to access the development version of dplyr to use the new across() function, I combined elements of both answers above to give the result i wanted:

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(if_else(is.na(.) & time == 0, mean(.[trt == "2" & time == 0]), .)))
```

It looks like across() is intended to replace the `_if` functions in the long run ([see here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/)), but this solution works in the meantime.